# Create web application with node js on tizen

Tags: node.js, tizen, tizen-web-app

Currently, I need to create a web application app with node js and run the code on the Samsung tv emulator of tizen studio.
Can anyone please help me with this?
Like:-

1. From where to start
2. how to create an app and compile it with Tizen studio

Comment: this is too vague. Can you code JS and node? what have you tried? what is tizen TV and how does that run node-js code?

Comment: Actually, I need to create tizen web application using node js.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Comment: @PrathameshMore, I haven't started building the application with nodejs because i am not getting proper approach to start with.

I have done following research :-
1) http://reinvantveer.github.io/2019/05/05/tizen-web-apps-using-node-and-webpack.html
2)  https://developer.tizen.org/blogs/stewartchristie/2013/running-node.js-on-tizen-2.0

But this are not up to the mark. so need some more clarification on this

Comment: @Vetras Tizen is samsung operating system, and we can develope applications for samsung devices like smartTV, Watches and mobile. Using tizen studio

Comment: @PrathameshMore I was able to follow the approach of second link, but it doesn't complete my requirement.

Comment: @ParthAgrawal those links are ancient. I doubt that info is still correct. please state your problem better using the edit feature to add more information on you question.

Comment: Ok @Vetras.
Let me provide some more information, regarding this question.

Comment: @Vetras As we can create web application (by using javascript, html, css) from tizen studio. So the part which we are doing with js, html and css need to replace it by nodejs. how can i achive this?

Comment: Sorry, I cant help as I dont understand the problem. But if you want to serve a website with node check express.js -- https://expressjs.com/

Comment: Ok @Vetras Thank you for your support.
I will manage.